# Jenkins URL for local GIT repository on Windows 10

Tags: git, jenkins, local

I'm "getting started" with Jenkins on Windows 10 and I've hit a wall with the URL for the repository.  I have a trivial HelloWorld at %HOMEPATH%\Documents\tmp\HelloWorld, which I can clone from the Windows 10 command prompt with "git clone".  Here's the transaction:

```
C:\Users\daryl\tmp>git clone %HOMEPATH%\Documents\tmp\HelloWorld
Cloning into 'HelloWorld'...
done.

C:\Users\daryl\tmp>dir
```

and then I can see that the data is well and truly there.

But when I put %HOMEPATH%\Documents\tmp\HelloWorld in the URL of the new Jenkins project, I get a an error when I look at the configuration along with an explanation that says

```
Specify the URL of this remote repository. This uses the same syntax as your git clone command.
```

The actual error code makes it look like Jenkins insists on talking to a server.  I can respect that.  But I want to keep things local so I can work offline.  That leaves me with two questions:

1. Am I right in my conclusion, or is there a way to finesse Jenkins into accessing my local filesystem?
2. What is a good lightweight Git server that runs on Windows 10?  (in case I have to do so)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* clone from local as well using the following syntax: `file://c:/test/playground` where `c:\test\playground` contains your repo.

[image]

For the Git server part, i am *assuming* you have [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) set up. If that's there, you may follow [this](https://medium.com/@piteryo7/how-to-set-up-git-server-on-local-network-windows-tutorial-7ec5cd2df3b1) tutorial for setting up Git server

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the git bash setup to create a named .git file in the folder.  Once that was added, I could "git push" and Jenkins could do the necessary "git clone" equivalent.  All is well.  Thanks.